# Block access to Google Play Store app from Wi-Fi router

Tags: google-play-store, router

I was wondering how can I block the Play Store Android app from the router itself?

My router has a function to block a web address or an IP address.

So does anyone know what website/IP address should I block to make the Play Store app not able to connect?

Answer (score 0):

play.google.com should block all access to the play store. Be aware that won't prevent the phone from installing apps from other sources.